# Printing out the factorials from 1-20 using a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

My program is running great, but the only problem is the factorial of the number 2 is 2 not 1. It's giving 2's value to 3 and so on. Therefore, the output is a line ahead, the factorial of 20 is 2,432,902,008,176,640,000.

P.S this is not 'Homework' its just programming as a hobby.

```
public class Factorials {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int counter;
    long factorials = 1;
    //        long total = 1;

    System.out.printf("%4s%30s\n", "Number", "Factorials");

    for (counter = 1; counter <= 20; factorials *= counter, counter++)
        System.out.printf("%4d%,30d\n", counter, factorials);

  }
}
```

Output:

```
Number                    Factorials

   1                              1
   2                              1
   3                              2
   4                              6
   5                             24
   6                            120
   7                            720
   8                          5,040
   9                         40,320
  10                        362,880
  11                      3,628,800
  12                     39,916,800
  13                    479,001,600
  14                  6,227,020,800
  15                 87,178,291,200
  16              1,307,674,368,000
  17             20,922,789,888,000
  18            355,687,428,096,000
  19          6,402,373,705,728,000
  20        121,645,100,408,832,000
```

help me please :)

Comment: Take the business logic out of the loop definition. It'll compile and it'll run, but it's not going to be readable, and it's going to produce confusing results (as you've noticed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
for(counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter++){
    factorials *= counter;
    System.out.printf("%4d%,30d\n", counter, factorials);

}
```

It is more "clean"(java standard) to have the `for-loop` like this: `for(x; x<=y; x++)` and then between these `{}` have the other logic/calculations.

Comment: @Carlton - you have an extra comma in your loop definition.

Comment: @jackal there was a extra comma in my code, edited that out. it should work now.

Answer (score 4):

Use this :

```
for (counter = 1; counter <= 20;counter++, factorials *= counter) {
    System.out.printf("%4d%,30d\n", counter, factorials);
}
```

You were needed to increment `counter` than `factorials *= counter`. that's it.

**Output :**

```
Number                    Factorials
   1                             1
   2                             2
   3                             6
   4                            24
   5                           120
   6                           720
   7                         5,040
   8                        40,320
   9                       362,880
  10                     3,628,800
  11                    39,916,800
  12                   479,001,600
  13                 6,227,020,800
  14                87,178,291,200
  15             1,307,674,368,000
  16            20,922,789,888,000
  17           355,687,428,096,000
  18         6,402,373,705,728,000
  19       121,645,100,408,832,000
  20     2,432,902,008,176,640,000
```